# How to get link from ArrayList filling by Jsoup

Tags: java, android, arraylist, jsoup

I trying to parse website. After all links collect to ArrayList, I wanna parse them again, but I have trouble with initialization of them.

This is my ArrayList:

```
public ArrayList<String> linkList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

How I collect links in "doInBackground":

```
            try {
                Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://forurl.com/archive/").get();
                Element links = doc.select("a[href]");
                for (Element link : links) 
                {

                    linkList.add(link.attr("abs:href"));
                }
            }
```

In "onPostExecute" showing what I get:

```
lk.setText("Collected: " +linkList.size()); // showing how much is collected
lj.setText("First link: " +linkList.get(0)); // showing first link
```

Try to parse child links:

```
public class imgTread extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        Bitmap bitmap;
        String[] url = {"http://forurl.com/link1/",   
                "http://forurl.com/link2/"};    // this way work well

protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < url.length; i++){
            Document doc1 = Jsoup.connect(url[0]).get(); // connect to 1 link for example
            Elements img = doc1.select("#strip");
            String imgSrc = img.attr("src");
            InputStream input = new java.net.URL(imgSrc).openStream();
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
        }
```

I traing to make String[] from ArrayList, but it doesn't work.

```
String[] url = linkList.toArray(new String[linkList.size()]);
```

Output for this way will be `Ljava.lang.String;@45ds364`

The idea is 1) collected all links from url; 2) Connect to them 1 by 1 and get that information what I need. 
First point work, the second too, but how tie it.
Thanks for any advise.

Working code:

```
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get(); // connect to site
            Elements links = doc.select("a[href]"); // get all links
            String link_addr = links.get(3).attr("abs:href"); // choose 3 link
            Document link_doc = Jsoup.connect(link_addr).get(); // connetect to it

            Elements img = link_doc.select("#strip"); // get all elements by tag #strip
            String imgSrc = img.attr("src");  // get url
            InputStream input = new java.net.URL(imgSrc).openStream();
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
```

I hope this helps someone.

Comment: Your code is confusing.. Is `LinkList` your `ArrayList` object? What do you want to do with that object? What is it really that you want to achieve? You have to provide more information, and include only the relevant code with clear explanations.

Comment: Tried to clean up and explain that I want to get. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing many unnecessary steps. You have a perfectly fine collection of `Element` objects in your `Elements links` object. Why do you have to add them to an ArrayList?

If I have understood your question correctly, your thought process should be something like this.

1. Get all the links from a URL
2. Establish a new connection to each link
3. Download all the images on that page where the element id = "strip".

Get all the links:

```
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
    Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
    doInBackground(links);
```

Call the `doInBackground` method with the links as a parameter:

```
public static void doInBackground(Elements links) throws IOException {
    try {
        for (Element element : links) {
            //Connect to the first link
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(element.attr("abs:href")).get();

            //Select all the elements with ID 'strip'
            Elements img = doc.select("#strip");

            //Get the source of the image
            String imgSrc = img.attr("abs:src");

            //Open an InputStream
            InputStream input = new java.net.URL(imgSrc).openStream();
            //Get the image
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            ...
            //Perhaps save the image somewhere?

            //Close the InputStream
            input.close();
        }
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Of course, you will have to properly use `AsyncTask` and call the methods from preferred places, but this is the overall idea of how you can use Jsoup to do the job you want it to.

Comment: Thanks, your advise helped and reading API too. Also your's solutions is better, will be next step for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want create a array instead of list you can do:

```
         try {
                Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://forurl.com/archive/").get();
                Element links = doc.select("a[href]");
                String array = new String[links.size();
                for (int i = 0; i < links.size(); i++) 
                {
                   array[i] = link.attr("abs:href");
                }
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all what the hell is that?
Why `link` variable is a collection of `Elements` and `links` is a single member of that collection?? Isn't that confusing?
Second, keep to java naming convention and name variables with noncapitalized letters so change `LinkList` to `linkList`. Even syntax highlighter got crazy thanks to you.

Third

> traing to make String[] from ArrayList, but it doesn't work.

Where are you trying to do that and it does not work? I don't see it anywhere in the code.

Forth

To create `Array` out of `List` you have to do something like that

```
String links[]=linksList.toArray(new String[linksList.size()]);
```

Fifth

Change the topic to more apropriate, as present one is very missleading (you have no trouble with Jsoup here)

Comment: 1) done. 2) done. 3) done. 4) try it, didnt help. 5) try it. Thanks man.

Comment: Are you sure? You are invoking `toString()` on array object so what kind of output did you expect? try `System.out.println(url[0])`